# How to generate dynamic bar chart in laravel using chart.js

Tags: jquery, laravel, charts, chart.js

I want generate a Dynamic Bar Chart in php laravel framework,
I have loans & payments Each users have its loans and payments below is the database 
where `Loan_tbl.id=payments_tbl.id`

**Loan_tbl**

```
  id  installment_value    fees  total_amount  remain_amount  paid_amount  remain_payments_duration  start_date  end_date             created_at           updated_at  approved_date  
------  -----------------  ------  ------------  -------------  -----------  ------------------------  ----------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  ---------------
  3754              35.33   12.00        212.00          70.68       141.32                         2  2020-01-01  2020-07-01  2020-06-04 15:09:30  2020-06-04 15:13:56  2020-06-04     
  3755              53.00   18.00        324.00         218.00       106.00                         4  2020-03-01  2020-11-01  2020-06-04 15:10:27  2020-06-04 15:15:29  2020-06-04     
  3756              70.67   24.00        424.00           0.00       424.00                         0  2020-06-01  2020-12-01  2020-06-04 15:10:37  2020-06-04 15:16:18  2020-06-04
```

**Payments_tbl**

```
  id  amount  due_date    payment_date  paid_amount  payment_method  status  loan_id           created_at           updated_at  
------  ------  ----------  ------------  -----------  --------------  ------  -------  -------------------  ---------------------
 77704   35.33  2020-01-01  2020-01-04          35.33               1       4     3754  2020-06-04 15:11:21    2020-06-04 15:13:51
 77705   35.33  2020-02-01  2020-02-04          35.33               1       4     3754  2020-06-04 15:11:21    2020-06-04 15:13:52
 77706   35.33  2020-03-01  2020-03-04          35.33               1       4     3754  2020-06-04 15:11:21    2020-06-04 15:13:53
 77707   35.33  2020-04-01  2020-04-04          35.33               1       4     3754  2020-06-04 15:11:21    2020-06-04 15:13:56
 77708   35.33  2020-05-01  2020-05-01         (NULL)               1       2     3754  2020-06-04 15:11:21    2020-06-04 15:11:21
 77709   35.33  2020-06-01  2020-06-01         (NULL)               1       2     3754  2020-06-04 15:11:21    2020-06-04 15:11:21
 77710    0.00  2020-03-01  2020-03-01         (NULL)               1       5     3755  2020-06-04 15:11:32    2020-06-04 15:15:05
 77711    0.00  2020-04-01  2020-04-01         (NULL)               1       5     3755  2020-06-04 15:11:32    2020-06-04 15:14:46
 77712   53.00  2020-05-01  2020-05-04          53.00               1       4     3755  2020-06-04 15:11:32    2020-06-04 15:15:28
 77713   53.00  2020-06-01  2020-06-04          53.00               1       4     3755  2020-06-04 15:11:32    2020-06-04 15:15:29
 77714   53.00  2020-07-01  2020-07-01         (NULL)               1       2     3755  2020-06-04 15:11:32    2020-06-04 15:11:32
 77715   53.00  2020-08-01  2020-08-01         (NULL)               1       2     3755  2020-06-04 15:11:32    2020-06-04 15:11:32
 77716   70.67  2020-06-01  2020-06-04          70.67               1       4     3756  2020-06-04 15:11:39    2020-06-04 15:15:56
 77717   70.67  2020-07-01  2020-07-04         353.35               1       6     3756  2020-06-04 15:11:39    2020-06-04 15:16:18
 77718   70.67  2020-08-01  2020-08-01           0.00               1       6     3756  2020-06-04 15:11:39    2020-06-04 15:16:17
 77719   70.67  2020-09-01  2020-09-01           0.00               1       6     3756  2020-06-04 15:11:39    2020-06-04 15:16:17
 77720   70.67  2020-10-01  2020-10-01           0.00               1       6     3756  2020-06-04 15:11:39    2020-06-04 15:16:18
 77721   70.67  2020-11-01  2020-11-01           0.00               1       6     3756  2020-06-04 15:11:39    2020-06-04 15:16:18
 77722   53.00  2020-09-01  2020-09-01         (NULL)               1       2     3755  2020-06-04 15:14:46    2020-06-04 15:15:05
 77723   59.00  2020-10-01  2020-10-01         (NULL)               1       2     3755  2020-06-04 15:15:05    2020-06-04 15:15:05
```

The query which I used to get the loans with the payments is below:

```
SELECT l.id,l.`borrower_id`,l.`start_date`,l.`total_amount`,l.`remain_amount`,
l.`paid_amount`,p.payment_date,p.paid_amount,p.id, 
l.end_date,l.created_at, l.updated_at FROM loans l JOIN
payments p ON l.id=p.loan_id
```

I have applied various logic but failed to achieve below is the js file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
var data = new Array();
    var labels = new Array();
    var payments = new Array();

    @foreach($loan_data as $loan)
      labels.push(new Date("{{$loan->start_date}}").toLocaleDateString('zh-Hans-CN'));
      data.push('{{$loan->total_amount}}');
      payments.push('{{$loan->remain_amount}}');
    @endforeach
    renderChart(data, labels,payments);

    function renderChart(data, labels,payments) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Total Loan Amt',
                    data:  data,
                    backgroundColor: '#26aaff',
                  //   borderColor: "rgba(0,114,188,1)",
                    borderWidth: 4,
                },{
                  label: "Remain AMt",
                  backgroundColor: "#4ddec1",
                  // borderColor: "blue",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  data: payments
                  }
               ],
            },
            options: {
               scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        barPercentage: 0.4
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        }
                    }]
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        tension: 0 
                    }
                }
            },
        });
    }
```

Expected Output that I want is in below image, for more reference check Image:
[image: Click to View Image]

I want the bar in below sequence `1 Bar=>Loan 1, 2nd Bar=> Loan1-Payments1, 3rd Bar=>Loan1-Payments2, 4th Bar=>Loan1 Remaining + Loan2, 5thBar=> 4thbar - Loan1 Payments3`..... and so on.

Plz help me out with this graph.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your function for rendering the chart you are passing the data for each dataset as a parameter. Instead, modify your backend to fetch the data for all datasets to look like:

```
{
  "Loans": [2],
  "Payments": [3]
  ...
}
```

I've added a function in my JS to set the data accordingly for my chart:

```
function getChartData(data) {
let chartData = {
    labels: ["# of records"], // on your case this is enough
    datasets: []
};
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(label, index) {
    chartData.datasets.push({
        label: label,
        data: Object.values(data[label]),
        borderColor: colors[index]
    });
});

return chartData;
}
```

`colors` is just an array with hex color strings, as many as you like. I've created a function to generate a random color if the datasets become too many.

Then when I create my chart I simply pass the result of that function to the `data` of the chart.

You'll have modify this depending on your backend. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/matrixatp/vr5efn81/41/) fiddle.